# How do I create a new environment in LaTeX that behaves as a table but has a different label and a separate counter?

Tags: latex

I am working on my thesis and the conventions in my area (Linguistics and Conversation Analysis) are that pieces of speech broken up line by line are called 'Fragments'. I have created the fragments as I like but I had to use the table environment to do so, and so they are all called tables.

I'm worried about renewing the \setcounter command because it will mess up my future tables, and I know that I can change the name of individual tables to be fragments but I can't help but think there must be an easy way to create an extra .sty package and simply invent a new environment using the code for a normal table with new names but I have NO idea how to do that. Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is package that allows to define floating environments. It is called [newfloat](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/caption/newfloat.pdf) and should be in most latex distributions.

You can define environments and customize their behavior.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newfloat}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[fileext=lof,listname={List of fragments}, 
                            name=Fragment, placement=h]{fragment}

\begin{document}
\begin{fragment}
  \fbox{blah, blah}
\caption{This is fragment 1}
\end{fragment}

\begin{fragment}
  \fbox{Blah, blah blah}
  \caption{This is another fragment}
\end{fragment}
\end{document}
```

[image]